# Redirect image from web page

Tags: php

I am going to build a interface to fetch the data from another web page by phpquery. but there is the captcha image and I can't fetch the captcha image.

I can't also print the output of phpquery

here is the code for redirect the image

```
 phpQuery::$debug = true;
  $result = phpQuery::newDocumentFile($url);
  echo $result;
  foreach(pq('.whoContentTable') as $tag) {
     foreach(pq($tag)->find('div.LBD_CaptchaImage') as $td) {
       print $td;
```

The output for the code:

```
    Found: div.podContent, comparing with matchClasses()

    Found: div.LBD_CaptchaDiv, comparing with matchClasses()

    Found: div.LBD_CaptchaImage, comparing with matchClasses()

    Found: div.LBD_CaptchaIcons, comparing with matchClasses()

    Found: div#whoisverify_ctl00_cphcontent_ctlcaptcha_SoundPlaceholder.LBD_placeholder, comparing with matchClasses()

    Found: input#ctl00_cphContent_btnVerifyCode.btnVerifyCode.WhoisMainSprite[name="ctl00$cphContent$btnVerifyCode"], comparing with matchClasses()
```

How can I get the output content form the page?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the HTML content of the target website? If so, try `file_get_contents()`:

```
echo file_get_contents("http://urlOfWebsite.com");
```

From that you can save the output of the function to a variable and parse the HTML to get the elements you want.

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: i have used and try for file_get_content(). but the captcha image cant be fetch.

Comment: @user1120482 What happens that prevents you from getting it?

Comment: i have to get the content (image of captcha) from the page.

Comment: It'll depend on how the captcha system is implemented and integrated into the site you're trying to access. Can you give us the website URL so we can check?

Comment: it is "http://who.godaddy.com/whoisverify.aspx?domain=relible.com&prog_id=godaddy" and i have to get the captcha image.

Comment: The image is being dynamically generated, every request to get the image will return a new one. As I've never needed to so such thing, I really don't know how to help you here. I suggest you rewrite your question to specifically say you're trying to get a dynamically generated captcha image with a link to the godaddy site, and if after rewriting the question you still don't get any answers I'll consider starting a bounty.